# Powershell's Join-Path Errs when Passing Path via Pipeline

Tags: powershell, filepath, powershell-4.0

`Join-Path` allegedly accepts the `Path` parameter from the pipeline.

This suggests that the two functions below should both work alike:

```
join-path 'c:\temp' 'x'     #returns c:\temp\x
'c:\temp' | join-path 'x'   #throws an error
```

However the second call (i.e. using passing the Path parameter by value to the pipeline) gives the below error:

> join-path : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the 
>   input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + 'c:\temp' | join-path 'x'
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (c:\temp:String) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

NB: Since `path` may be an array I also tried `[array]('c:\temp') | join-path 'x'`; but this made no difference.

Have I misunderstood something, or is this a bug in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, an expression `join-path 'c:\temp' 'x'` is interpreted by PowerShell as `Join-Path -Path 'c:\temp' -ChildPath 'x'` (because the names for positional parameters `Path` and `ChildPath` are optional).

In your second example, you are passing a pipeline parameter `'c:\temp'` to the command `Join-Path -Path 'x'` (not the absence of `ChildPath` parameter). It will not work because `Join-Path` accepts only `Path` parameter from the pipeline but you have already defined it.

If you want to bind *another*, not first parameter, you should write it name explicitly, as in

```
'c:\temp' | Join-Path -ChildPath 'x'
# => 'c:\temp\x'
```

Comment: Ah of course; so passing parameter 1 by pipeline doesn't cause parameter 2 to move up the chain.  Slightly annoying language design, but at least it makes sense; thank-you.

Comment: @JohnLBevan, I'd just say that parameter binding happens on an expression parsing stage, _before_ the parser knows you're about to pass something from the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @ForNeVeR; good to know there's an underlying reason for that design choice.